# User Authentication over multiple Webservers in azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, single-sign-on, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET Application which runs an multiple Web Servers in Azure (these are all virtual machines and not Azure Websites).

If a user logs himself in (currently forms authentication) everything is fine but if he clicks on a link he might get redirected to another server in the server group where the session cookie is not set.

How could that be solved in azure so that a user is logged in on all machines or is there a way to "bind" a user to a specific server so that he won't jump between the servers?

Thanks for your help!
metabolic

Comment: See [if this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10555000/304683)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the session state to be saved in an external persistence solution, like SQL Server or Redis, instead of InProc (which means in memory) which is the setting you have now. The steps to do that are described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) for SQL Server. Then if someone ends up in a different server, he'll still be authenticated as the session will be loaded from the persistence solution.

Comment: Thank you! I ended with using Redis Cache for this problem