# Access ASP.NET Session in SQL Server mode across multiple applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session

I'm trying to access the shared Sessions stored in SQL Server from multiple applications in different servers.

I already read this [Sharing sessions across applications using the ASP.NET Session State Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service/3151315#3151315) but I had no luck.

Here's how I set up the web.config of both applications:

```
<sessionState 
    mode="SQLServer"
    allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"
    sqlConnectionString="Application Name=MyAppName; Data Source=MyDataSource; Initial Catalog=MyDBName; User Id=MyUser; Password=MyPassword"
    cookieless="false" 
    timeout="250" 
/>
```

And here is the machine key I set up in both config files:

```
<machineKey validationKey="key1" decryptionKey="key2" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

Both the applications can read and write the database.

I also tweaked the `TempGetAppID` stored procedure to overcome the application name limitations. In such way my **SessionID**s share the same suffix.

That said, I still have 2 different records in the `ASPStateTempSessions` table, with different **SessionID**s.

Here's an example:

```
3nn53mh3j0vf3mrravuda11o9c8d4bee
oljchatkqzcje1ae1b3n2pst9c8d4bee
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

**EDIT 1**

I tried with both Chrome and IE on a single tab.

Comment: Is that really your machine key or are you just posting that for security reasons? Note that you can't just stick any value in there: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey.aspx

Comment: I am not sure if you also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555000/losing-session-state-with-asp-net-sql-server. (There is more than one possible reason, maybe one of those answers will solve your issue)

Comment: @NightOwl888 That isn't my machine key, it's only for example purpose.

Comment: @helix I already read that article but I couldn't find a solution in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

The problem was that I was (stupidly) trying to share the session between two applications with different host names. In such way, the SessionID was correctly stored in SQL Server but, while one of the applications was able to generate and store the SessionID in the cookie, the other application could not read such cookie because of the different domain.